# How to get the length of the array equal to the length of a string?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, class, netbeans

I hope I can get my point across in this.

- In the `isoddeven` function, I count the number of letters or digits/special symbols depending on, whether the length of the variable n is odd or even. Then I take the count variable.

  And return its value, so that I can use it as the length for the char array.

When I run my code, it brings out a total number that exceeds the total of the actual count(it doubles). I can't use regrex in this part, it needs to be a loop that counts.

Really need some advice on anything I should add. Or is there anything that's actually wrong with my code?

This is the output i want :

```
    enter a string :
    rain!21
    length is odd, there are 3 non-alphabetic characters in the string
    enter 3 strings in the array
    **********
```

the output i get instead :

```
    enter a string :
    joy!@u77
    length is even, there are 4 aplabetic characters in the string
    **********
    enter 8 strings in the array
    **********
```

Here is my code :

```
    import java.io.*;
    public class Stringarray {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        String n;
        String arr[] = new String [4];
        int c = 0, c2 = 0, i;
        char ch;
        
         public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
             Stringarray obj = new Stringarray ();
             
             obj.Constructor ();
             obj.stringInput ();
             obj.IsOddEven ();
             obj.createArray ();
             obj.replaceDigit ();
         }//main
         
         public void Constructor () {
             System.out.println("your name and section here ");
         }//constructor
         
         public int stringInput () throws IOException {
             System.out.println("enter a string :");
             n = input.readLine();
            return n.length();
         }//stringInput
         
         public int IsOddEven () {
             if (n.length() % 2 == 0) {
                 for ( i = 0; i<n.length(); i++){
                     ch = n.charAt(i);
                     if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z' || ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z' ){
                     c++;//letters
                     }
                 }
                 System.out.println("length is even, there are " + c + " aplabetic characters in the string");
             }
             else {
                 for (i = 0; i<n.length(); i++){
                     if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'){
                         c++;//digits
                     }
                     else {
                         c2++;//special characters
                     }
                 }
                 System.out.println("length is odd, there are " + c+c2 + " non-alphabetic characters in the string");
             }
             int x = c + c2;
             System.out.println("**********");
             return x;
         }//IsOddEven
         
         public void createArray() throws IOException {
             System.out.println("enter " + n.length() +" strings in the array\n**********");
             for (int i = 0; i<n.length(); i++){
                 n = input.readLine();
                 arr[i] = n;
             }
             System.out.println("**********");
         }//createArray
         
         public void replaceDigit () {
             System.out.println("all digits in the array are replaced with #");
             for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
                 arr[i] = arr[i].replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z!]", "#");
                 System.out.println(arr[i]);
             }
         }//replaceDigit
         
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a nice example of a sphagetti code and there are too many issues to list them all. I would advise you to read 'Clean Code' - it will definitely help you to improve your coding skills.

Regarding the original question, look at your method `createArray`. It uses `n.length()` instead of your counters, i.e. the length of the input line. I assume that's not what you actually want from it.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is at `System.out.println("enter " + n.length() +" strings in the array\n**********");`. You are using `n.length()` for how many it should add, so in the case of `joy!@u77` the length is 8 casing it to add 8 to the array. Judging by your code, I think you would want to do `"enter " + x +" strings...`. Not sure if your storing it in `x`, but the problem lies at `n.length()`.